# How to determine how many rows and columns are in a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to identify how many rows and columns are in a pandas Dataframe called df, I tried using the functions:
***len(df)*** =>  I get only the number of rows
***len(df.columns)*** => I get only the number of columns

Is there a single command/function that will reveal the rows and columns?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After quick research I found I can use:

***df.shape***

Answer comes back as (# of rows, # of columns)

For example if df has 421 rows and 33 columns then:
***df.shape*** will respond
(421,33)